# String manipulation - Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

can anyone help me with a project I am stuck on, iv'e tried to simplify what I'm trying to achieve as best I can.

I have an input that can be anything in this format `/_/_/_/_*`

Using javascript/jquery I am trying to achieve something like the below. I don't know how best to approach it though

input = /user/app/folder/TOM*

output = https://myscript.com/user/assemblies/app/operations/environments/folder/

Comment: The link does not open

Comment: I don't think jquery will help you. Did you look into regex? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: I played with regex but it hurt my head, I thought maybe splice but I'm new to JS but thats what I'm working in

Comment: Expresso is a neat tool that's great for creating, testing and understanding RegExs. Was put onto it the other year and now when I'm forced to, I reach for it instead of paracetamol and ibuprofen. :laughs: It's here: http://www.ultrapico.com/expresso.htm

Comment: what happened to `TOM*`? and what's the general logic in this? will the input always consist of 3 parts? And will this always output to the same structure, just injecting these three folders at the respective places? how do you handle a `//` in the input?

Comment: Why do people always run to regexes when often simple string functions do the job; in this case [String#split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split). `var parts = input.split('/');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a little confusing exactly what you are asking. Perhaps if you give a few more examples or a sample of what code you have tried so far someone could be of more help. 
Also, is the asterisk at the end of your input signifying something like a wildcard or is it just an asterisk?

As far as I can tell you are trying to do a variety of string intercolation.

```
var input= "/input1/input2/input3/input4*";
intercolateIntoPath(input);  
--> "https://apple/input1/banana/input2/orange/input3/mango/input4*"
```

Here is fairly simple implementation of that functionality. There are others and even some much nicer syntax options in newer versions of Javascript (ES6) that isn't supported on all browsers yet:

```
function intercolateIntoPath(input) {
    var inputPieces= input.split('/');
    var outputPieces = [
        'https://apple', inputPieces[0], 'banana', inputPieces[1],
        'orange', inputPieces[2], 'mango', inputPieces[3]
    ];
    return outputPieces.join('/');
}
```